# Generating function of factorable binary words

Tags: reference-request, formal-languages, generating-functions

A word $w$ on the alphabet $A := \{0, 1\}$ is *factorable* if
\begin{equation}
    w = u^k \mbox{ where } u \in A^* \mbox{ and } k \geq 2.
\end{equation}

Let $L$ be the language of the set of factorable words on $A$ and $f(t)$ be its generating series, that is
\begin{equation}
    f(t) := \sum_{n \geq 0} |L \cap A^n| \; t^n.
\end{equation}

> What is the generating function of $L$?

Comment: Is $k$ a positive integer or is it a word over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$?  I think you mean that $w$ and $u$ are words, instead of $w$ and $k$.

Comment: Your are asking for primitive words over a binary alphabet. The coefficients of the generating series you are looking for are the ones of Sequence A056267 of the OEIS. (And please, make an effort in writing your question.)

Comment: @SamueleGiraudo,what is  Sequence A056267 of the OEIS?thank you

Comment: http://oeis.org/A056267

Comment: @SamueleGiraudo,thank you ,I have gotten it by searching

Comment: the coefficients of length P prime is $$2^P-2$$,but other coefficients of length m which may have many factors of integers  are difficult to compute

Comment: It seems the coefficients of length m which may have many factors of integers  are difficult to compute,but it is asymptotically  $$2^m$$

Comment: @SamueleGiraudo,thank you very much for you editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordinary generating function is a fairly horrible Lambert expansion (usually with a natural boundary). For more on this subject look in my old paper *[Walks on Free Groups and other Stories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5947)*.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more relevant reference to OEIS than Samuele Giraudo gave is http://oeis.org/A027375. In particular, there one finds the formula 
 $$
a_n = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)2^{n/d}
 $$
which in fact easily follows from the definition by means of Moebius inversion. For more than two letters, you should replace $2$ above by the number of letters.

This formula shows that a closed expression for the generating function is too much to hope for. Maybe you should think a bit more what you need it for, and whether you can avoid using it.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that http://oeis.org/A056267 and http://oeis.org/A027375 are duplicate.

Comment: @VladimirDorsenko,thank you,your post are also the answer,but it is permissible to choose only one answer

Comment: @XL _at_China: it's up to you which answer to accept. I failed to extract information giving a clear answer to your question from the paper of Igor, so I posted this answer, but you should not feel obliged to accept it if Igor's answer is sufficient for you :-)

Comment: @SamueleGiraudo: I actually just noticed that OEIS says "A027375, A038199 and A056267 are all essentially the same sequence with different initial terms."